# collapsing in angular overlapping

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a chatborad app where there are comments under each post, but I am making a button that collapse all the comments for better view especially when they grow.

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of commentArr">{{ comment.body }}
        <div class="input-group-prepend float-right">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">{{ comment.userName }}</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

right now all comments is being added while they're collapsed although i'm using "show" because i want them to be shown upon adding them, then if they grow up i can collapse them.

the other problem is that, right now when i click the collapse button in any of "the blue add comment buttons shown in the screenshot" it only collapses the comments for the first post, how can i make every add button collapses it own comments?

thank you!

[see the blue button for collapsing comments, adding comments is bound with onEnter()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xH8e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way.

example app:

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  hotels = [
    {name: 'Hotel1', comment: 'Hotel1 info'},
    {name: 'Hotel2', comment: 'Hotel2 info'},
    {name: 'Hotel3', comment: 'Hotel3 info'}

  ];
  prevHotel: any;

  changeIsShohToTrue(hotel) {
    if (this.prevHotel && this.prevHotel.expand && this.prevHotel !== hotel) {
      hotel.expand = false;
    }
    hotel.expand = !hotel.expand;
    this.prevHotel = hotel;

  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
    <div>{{ hotel.name }}</div>
    <div>
      <button (click)="changeIsShohToTrue(hotel)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn"><i
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="hotel.expand">Comment: {{hotel.comment}}</div>
  </div>
```